# Display the selected category when selecting from a drop down

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I want to show the name of the category selected from a drop-down when someone searches in the category.

The page should show search results for "category name here."

I tried using `get_search_query();` but it shows only the results from the search form, doesn't work on drop-downs.

Comment: Have you tried using `wp_dropdown_categories` ?

Answer (score 0):

You will get all queried object with this function:

```
 <?php
 $queried_object = get_queried_object();
 var_dump( $queried_object );
 ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are to ways to handle it.

1. If your search page URL is similar like `http://YOURHOST/?s=query&category=uncategorized` then you can get the term object like;

   Add the following lines in main functions.php

   ```
   add_filter( 'query_vars', function($vars) {
       $vars[] = 'category';
       return $vars;
   } );
   ```

   Then in search.php get the value

   `$cat_slug = get_query_var('category');
   $term = get_category_by_slug( $cat_slug );
   $term_id = $term->term_id; // Here is your required id`
2. The 2nd way that your URL should be `http://YOURHOST/?s=query&cat=uncategorized` Then you can handle with `cat` parameter

   `$cat_slug = get_query_var('cat');
   $term = get_category_by_slug( $cat_slug );
   $term_id = $term->term_id; // Here is your required id`

Comment: Edited my answer try it now

Comment: This should work, but please note that I am using Search and Filter Pro Plugin for generating the search results. The search query looks like this  http://www.example.com/seminar-lists/?_sft_dt_portfolio_category=administration-secretarial

Comment: So you need to use the 1st point and replace `$var[] = '_sft_dt_portfolio_category'` and `$cat_slug = get_query_var( '_sft_portfolio_category' )`